# Ruby gem error installing rack-mount + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to install Rails 3.0 Beta but ran into what appears to be a dependency error:

```
$: sudo gem install rack-mount
Successfully installed rack-mount-0.5.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rack-mount-0.5.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-mount-0.5.1...



$: sudo gem install rails --prerelease
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    actionpack requires rack-mount (~> 0.4.0, runtime)
```

Why is it unable to recognize that rack-mount is already installed?

Comment: Both Damient and Chuck (below) are right. The problem is that you have to use the `--prerelease` flag for Rails, but Rubygems interprets `--prerelease` as applying to everything in that command. When Rails asks for `rack-mount 0.4.0`, Rubygems looks for `rack-mount 0.4.0 prerelease`, which doesn't exist. That's why there are two separate commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release/#comment-26380), you need `rack-mount` at exactly version 0.4.0. Install with the following command:

```
gem install rack-mount -v 0.4.0
```

Comment: Got this: `ERROR: could not find gem rack-mount locally or in a repository`

Answer (score 1):

```
gem install tzinfo builder memcache-client rack rack-test rack-mount erubis mail text-format thor bundler i18n
gem install rails --pre
```

If it still doesn't work make sure you drop the rack-mount gem.

My other question is whether you're using RVM or not.